# Toggle onclick with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have trouble with my code, and I'm still not sure how to solve my problem. I'm not even sure what the question is. Sorry if it's any confusing to you, I'm new to Jquery and not fluent in English.

The question:
I have this html:

```
<div id="plot_info">
  <ul>
        <li>Coordinates: <span id="coordinates">(e,e)</span></li>
        <li>Building: <span id="building">castle</span></li>
        <li>Terrain: <span id="terrain">soft</span></li>
        <li>Temperature: <span id="temperature">warm</span></li>
        <li>Humidity: <span id="humidity">normal</span></li>
        <li>Population: <span id="population">1000</span></li>
        <li>Money: <span id="money">$1000000</span></li>
        <li>Goods produced: <span id="goods_produced">none</span></li>
        <li>Corruption level: <span id="corruption_level">.33%<span></li>
        <li>Owned by: <span id="owned_by">user</span></li>
    </ul>
    <input id="change_plot_info" type="button" value="Change">
    <input id="set_plot_info" type="button" value="Set" disabled>
</div>
```

And I have this js:

```
$("#change_plot_info").click(function() {
        alert("Get ready to enter 'EDIT MODE'");
        $("#plot_info span").click(function() {
            var span_id = this.id;
            var span_text = $(this).text();
            $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' value='" + span_text + "' id='" + span_id + "'>");
            $("#change_plot_info").attr;
        });
    });
```

I would like it so when I press "Change", the same button is disabled, and the "Set" button is enabled. And so that when I press "Set" the `<input>` is converted back into a span. But I would like it so it is possible to toggle between the two.

As said before, I'm new to JQuery, so please be patient. Also keep in mind that I'm searching for the simplest and closest to my code, I'm not trying to just type less.

Any explanations of what you're doing are, as always, deeply appreciated.

Comment: Should each `<li>` have an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var isEditing = false;
$("#plot_info input[type=button]").click(function() {
    $("#plot_info ul li").each(function(){
      if (!isEditing) {
        var span_id = $(this).children('span').attr('id');
        var span_text = $(this).children('span').text();
        $(this).children('span').replaceWith('<input type="text" value="'+span_text+'" id="'+span_id+'">');
      } else {
        var input_id = $(this).children('input').attr('id');
        var input_val = $(this).children('input').val();
        $(this).children('input').replaceWith('<span type="text" id="'+input_id+'">'+input_val+'</span>');
        $(this).children('span').on("click", function(){editSpan($(this))});
      }
    });
  $("#plot_info input[type=button]").prop('disabled',false);
  $(this).prop('disabled',true);
  isEditing = !isEditing; // toggle boolean
});
  
$("#plot_info li span").on("click", function(){editSpan($(this))});
  
function editSpan(span){
  var span_id = span.attr('id');
  var span_text = span.text();
  span.replaceWith('<input type="text" value="'+span_text+'" id="'+span_id+'">');
  $("#change_plot_info").prop('disabled',true);
  $("#set_plot_info").prop('disabled',false);
  isEditing = true;
}

});
```

```css
span { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot_info">
  <ul>
        <li>Coordinates: <span id="coordinates">(e,e)</span></li>
        <li>Building: <span id="building">castle</span></li>
        <li>Terrain: <span id="terrain">soft</span></li>
        <li>Temperature: <span id="temperature">warm</span></li>
        <li>Humidity: <span id="humidity">normal</span></li>
        <li>Population: <span id="population">1000</span></li>
        <li>Money: <span id="money">$1000000</span></li>
        <li>Goods produced: <span id="goods_produced">none</span></li>
        <li>Corruption level: <span id="corruption_level">.33%<span></li>
        <li>Owned by: <span id="owned_by">user</span></li>
    </ul>
    <input id="change_plot_info" type="button" value="Change">
    <input id="set_plot_info" type="button" value="Set" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a bit of a problem with this solution. It is by far the easiest to understand and shorter in code, but you see, I was trying to make it so whenever you click on a `span`, the `span` transforms into `input`. and once set is clicked it is transformed back to `span`.

Comment: I ment that when you press "Change", each individual is editable, once you lose focus it goes back to `span`. You can only edit it once you clicked "Change". Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to capture all the span tag and input tag, then replace with appropriate contents as following code :

```
// Change Button
$("#change_plot_info").click(function() {
    alert("Get ready to enter 'EDIT MODE'");
    $(this).prop('disabled',true); //<-- disable this button after clicked
    $("#set_plot_info").prop('disabled',false); //<-- Enable set button
    $("#plot_info ul span").each(function(){
        var myVal = $(this).text(),id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' value='" + myVal + "' id='" + id + "'>");
    });
});

// Set button
$("#set_plot_info").click(function() {
    alert("SET");
    $(this).prop('disabled',true); //<-- disable this button after clicked
    $("#change_plot_info").prop('disabled',false); //<-- Enable change button
    $("#plot_info ul input").each(function(){
        var myVal = $(this).val(),id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).replaceWith("<span id='" + id + "'>"+myVal+"</span>");  
    });
 });
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j165am5z/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, when you click on change it toggles the button states and an input box appears, after you click Set it will replace the current value with the new one

```
<div id="plot_info">
        <ul>
            <li>Coordinates: <span id="coordinates">(e,e)</span> <span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Building: <span id="building">castle</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Terrain: <span id="terrain">soft</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Temperature: <span id="temperature">warm</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Humidity: <span id="humidity">normal</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Population: <span id="population">1000</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Money: <span id="money">$1000000</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Goods produced: <span id="goods_produced">none</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Corruption level: <span id="corruption_level">.33%</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
            <li>Owned by: <span id="owned_by">user</span><span class="txtChn"></span></li>
        </ul>
        <input id="change_plot_info" type="button" value="Change">
        <input id="set_plot_info" type="button" value="Set" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

here I added a span with a class `txtChn` which acts as a wrapper for the input

```
    $("#change_plot_info, #set_plot_info").click(function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).prop('disabled', true); // Disable clicked button
        $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled', false); // Enable the other one


// Use $(element).prop('disabled', true);  To disable
// Use $(element).prop('disabled', false);  To Enable 

        switch(ID){ // Verify which button has been clicked and trigger an event
            case "change_plot_info": 
// If change is clicked -> allow Editing
                $("#plot_info span").click(function() {
                    var span_id = this.id;
                    var span_text = $(this).text();
                    $(this).next('.txtChn').html("<input type='text' value= '"  + span_text +  "'>");
                });
                break;
            case"set_plot_info":
 // When set is clicked updated new values that are set

                $(".txtChn input").each(function(i,val) {
                  var  $this = $(this);
                    if(val){
                        $this.parent('.txtChn').siblings('span').text($this.val());
                    }

                });
                $(".txtChn").html('');  // remove edit inputs
                break;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I believe that this is a little too complex for me.

Comment: Nevermind, DrKey's answer is more complete and correct. You should perhaps do that